# Telegram web app no corre en dispositivos moviles

Tags: python, telegram, bot

Estoy desarrollando un bot de Telegram que basicamente envia un boto ( como respuesta el comando /start ) que al oprimir abre una web app. Una web app no es mas que una página HTML que se muestra en una ventanita pop up en lugar de abrir el navegador embebido, con algunas diferencias como el intercambio de información entre la app y el user, etc. Pero el punto es que no es más que un archivo HTML, alojado en un server HTTPS, que se abre. Como los Games de toda la vida.
Mi problema es que la web app corre perfectamente bien si la secuencia ( /start + boton + apertura de la app ) es ejecutada en la versión desktop de Telegram ( Telegram web ) pero no hace nada ( se queda en blanco ) si esta misma secuencia ocurre en un dispositivo móvil.

Algunas aclaraciones:

1 -Probe mas de un dispositivo con igual resultado.

2 -Probe mas de una librería para implementar el Telegram bot.

3 - La web app demo que describe la documentación de Telegram ( Durger King ), corre perfectamente bien tanto en móviles como en web. ( No note nada singular en esta. Incluso la copie y la intente correr desde mi servidor HTTPS por si había alguna diferencia que pasé por alto pero no corre tampoco.). Cualquier otra url como google.com corre perfectamente bien !!!

4 - Si envio la URL de mi página como mensaje de texto normal a un user, Telegram abre la página sin problemas en su navegador embebido o en cualquier otro que tengamos configurado para tal fin.

5 - Los certificados SSL para el servidor HTTPS los genero en [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/es/). Les vengo usando sin problemas en otros proyectos.

Se me ocurren dos cosas que podrían causar este problema:

1 - que mi servidor HTTPS no esté correctamente configurado y esto le molesta a la version móvil de Telegram pero no a la version web desktop

2 - que los certificados SSL no sean lo suficientemente seguros para Telegram en móviles pero si para la version web desktop.

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia por mas obvia o tonta que pueda sonar. Las probaré todas !! El diablo está siempre en los detalles.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Tal vez sería buena idea revisar el código del tal bot. No somos buenos adivinando.